# Locus of the intersection point of angle bisectors of angles made by 2 fixed lines

Tags: geometry, locus

"$AB$ and $CD$ are two fixed straight lines and a variable straight line cuts them at $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The angular bisectors of $\angle AXY$ and $\angle CXY$ meet at $P$. Find the locus of $P$."

First things first, if the question states $\angle CXY$, it is clear that their angle bisectors meet on line $AB$ and thus, $P$ lies on $AB$. I believe the question wanted to state "$\angle AXY$ and $\angle CYX$" instead. So I considered the question to be stated as,

"$AB$ and $CD$ are two fixed straight lines and a variable straight line cuts them at $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The angular bisectors of $\angle AXY$ and $\angle CYX$ meet at $P$. Find the locus of $P$."

My attempt:

It is trivial to note that had $AB$ and $CD$ been parallel, the locus would have been $\angle XPY=90^{\circ}$. Then I tried considering non-parallel lines.

Assume that $\angle AXY≥\angle BXY$, and $\angle CYX≥\angle BYX$ such that $\angle AXY= 2x$ and $\angle BXY= 2y$. Then, if $P$ lies on the side whose sum of interior angles$>180^{\circ}$, clearly $\angle XPY=180-(x+y)$. The same may be done for all combinations of relations of supplementary pairs $(\angle AXY,\angle BXY)$ and $(\angle CXY,\angle ∠DXY)$.

However, this is an EXTREMELY piece-wise definition (and subject to errors) and as a result, I'm not satisfied with it; there must be a way to refine my answer to produce a much more accurate and concise one. In short, I have 2 primary questions:

1. If my method of solving is correct, how do I refine my answer?
2. If I need to re-start from scratch, how do I start?

Thanks for the help!

Source: Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics

*Note: This may be marked a duplicate as I've seen the same question before. However as I couldn't find a satisfactory explanation there, I decided to post my own question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formulas.

Comment: @mag oh okay, thanks for the information. I'll try to use that after I've learnt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already considered the scenario where $AB\parallel CD$, i am considering these two straight lines two be non parallel.

Let $AB$ and $CD$ meet at point $Q$. Divide this into two cases.

[image: AB and CD straight lines]

Case $1:$  We get point $Q$ by extending $AB$ and $CD$ through points $A$ and $C$ respectively.

Then, in $\triangle QXY$, the internal bisectors of $\angle QXY$ and $\angle QYX$ meet at $P$.Hence, $P$ is the incentre of $\triangle QXY$ and thereafter the locus of $P$ is the bisector of $\angle Q$.

[image: AB and CD straight lines]

Case $2:$  We get point $Q$ by extending $AB$ and $CD$ through points $B$ and $D$ respectively.

Then, in $\triangle QXY$, the external bisectors of $\angle QXY$ and $\angle QYX$ meet at $P$. Hence, $P$ is the excentre of $\triangle QXY$ and thereafter the locus of $P$ is the bisector of $\angle Q$.

Thus, the locus of $P$ is the line which internally bisects the angle formed by the lines $AB$ and $CD$.

Comment: That's a very nice solution, didn't know it would be that simple but oh well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. I have that book actually. It's a really good material for olympiad preparation.

Comment: Yep, that's true.